# PowerShell - Remove all lines of text file until a certain string is found

Tags: powershell

I currently have an output log file that's a bit of a mess and grows quickly. It's the debug output for a large script that permissions mailboxes. I basically just want to delete every line in the file until it finds the first iteration of the date 7days ago.

So far, I can return all lines containing that date

```
$content = Get-Content $file
$lastweek = "{0:M/d/yyyy}" -f (get-date).AddDays(-7)

$content | Where-Object { $_.Contains("$lastweek") }
```

But I can not figure out a function to just wipe everything until that is found for the first time.

I have tried a -replace:

```
$content -replace ".*$lastweek", " " | Set-Content $file -Force
```

But that only seems to replace from the beginning of each line that contains the specified string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running V4, you can use the array `.Where()` method, with the '`SkipUntil`' option:

```
$content.Where({ $_ -like "*$lastweek*" },'SkipUntil')
```

Comment: That throws a Method error:
"Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'like'"

I got it to work with:
`$content.Where({ $_ -like ("*$lastweek*") },'SkipUntil')`

Thank you.

Comment: My fault.  I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only keep the entries containing your specified search string from that log file, you can do something to the effect of:

```
$content = Get-Content $file | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains "$lastweek"} 
$content | Set-Content $file -force
```

Replace `-notcontains "$lastweek"` with `-notlike "*$lastweek*"` if needed for better matching.

Comment: In my situation, I wanted to keep everything after the first iteration of that string. There are entries in the file on the hour all day long, so I didn't want to lose everything in between the lines with that date. Appreciate the response, though.