# Powershell: how to easily switch between 'Out-String' and 'Get-Content' string variable types?

Tags: powershell, parsing, multilinestring

I want to use the method given in the answer of this question:
[PowerShell - Remove all lines of text file until a certain string is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141437/powershell-remove-all-lines-of-text-file-until-a-certain-string-is-found)

However I don't get my string from "Get-Content"; I get it from "Out-String". How can I convert my "Out-String" variable into a "Get-Content" format without needing to "Set-Content"/"Get-Content" a temporary file? Or how can I get the same end result without even converting?

It really hurts my brains that a "Get-Member" on the variable from either 'Out-String' or 'Get-Content' returns a TypeName of System.String but you cannot use them the same way...

Here is the simplified code I've been trying to understand - let's use that:

```
# Let's work with the text from 'Get-Help' output:
$myString = (Get-Help | out-string)

# I only want the text from the "SEE ALSO" section:
$cut = $myString.Where({ $_ -like ("*SEE ALSO*") },'SkipUntil')
$cut # This shows the whole thing!!! :-(
$cut | gm | findstr TypeName # says 'TypeName: System.String'

# Dirty conversion to "Get-Content" format:
Set-Content "tmp.file" -value $cut
$recut = (Get-Content "tmp.file").Where({ $_ -like ("*SEE ALSO*") },'SkipUntil')
$recut # Now this shows what I want, even though the below returns 'TypeName: System.String' as well !!!
(Get-Content "tmp.file") | gm | findstr TypeName
```

Comment: Upvoted for finding a powershell command that outputs a multi-line string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is get-help (with no parameters) or out-string is outputting one multiline string (with windows line endings).  I even tried out-string -stream.  This is unusual for a powershell command.  Get-content would split up the lines for you automatically.

```
(get-help).count

1
```

One way to resolve it is to split on the line endings.  I'm also skipping blank lines at the end.  (This split pattern works with unix/osx text too.)

```
((get-help) -split '\r?\n').Where({ $_ -like '*SEE ALSO*' },'SkipUntil') | where { $_ } 

  SEE ALSO:
      about_Updatable_Help
      Get-Help
      Save-Help
      Update-Help
```

Or:

```
((get-help) -split '\r?\n').Where({ $_ -match 'SEE ALSO' },'SkipUntil').Where{ $_ }
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I just changed a bit the split characters to `\r?\n` so that it could be used with either Windows or Linux line endings.

Comment: I like that.  I modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you do not even need `Out-String`, but I will stick to your example:

```
$myString = (Get-Help | Out-String)
$mystring -match "(?ms)^.*(SEE\sALSO.*)$" | Out-Null
$Matches[1]
```

The key in the regex is `(?ms)`. `m` enables multi-line search and `s` enables wildcards to span over multiple lines (in other words: including line breaks). The result of the `-match` operator is piped to `Out-Null` to not see it in the terminal. You might want to evaluate it though. If `$true`, `$Matches[1]` will contain your desired string.

Comment: Thanks, but having tested that with other outputs than 'Get-Help', I find js2010's answer more reliable (and easier to understand too).